# extract subtext from specific part of string

Tags: unix

I would like to extract the text between the second dot "." and the first "%" in the text below. Any ideas where to start?

In

```
 Demux.SRhi10005.Endothelial%20Cells%20-%20Microvascular%2c%20donor2.SRhi10005_hg19.11342-117G1.AGTCAA.fastq.gz.sam.stderr
```

out

```
Endothelial
```

Comment: Take a look at the `sed` utility. You will find many examples for how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sample script like this (if positions are defined)

```
awk -F'[.%]' '{print $3}'
```

If you want to be very strict and you can have more delimiters (third dot for example) you can use something like:

```
awk -F\. '{print $3}'|awk -F\% '{print $1}'
```